# Is there a quick way to activate Cortana in Windows 11 other than by voice?

Tags: windows-11, cortana

In Windows 10, you could easily activate Cortana by pressing Win+C, but that no longer works in the latest version of the OS. Is there another way to do that? Perhaps using a command line (/CMD shortcut)?

Comment: Windows 10 21H2 : Win+C is still opening Cortana for me.

Comment: @harrymc 11 Yes, I know. I'm asking about Windows 11.

Comment: I took off the "windows" tag from your post, since it relates only to Windows 11.

Comment: Link is for W10, see if setting exists in W11>>>>https://winaero.com/cortana-listen-keyboard-shortcut-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 Pro. Start.  Enter Cortana in the Search bar.  Cortana comes up - sign in.  That should work. I did this on a couple of Windows 11 machines.

Once you have done that, you can Pin Cortana to Start and put it on the first page of Start. Start, Click, done.

Comment: Thanks John, I know how to open the Cortana app. The trouble is that by simply opening the app you don't activate the voice input directly. On Win 10 Cortana is listening immediately upon pressing the Win+C keys. I was hoping there was an alternative shortcut on Win 11.

Comment: I gave you a two click way to get into Cortana. I do not think there is a shorter way or shortcut as Microsoft now designs this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I have two hacky solutions for you.

1. Create a Desktop shortcut for Cortana (different from adding it to the taskbar). Right click the shortcut and select properties. In the properties menu you can create a keyboard shortcut.
2. If you have a mouse with extra buttons such as a gaming mouse or a windows mouse. I assigned the following macro to the extra mouse button:

   (Windows Key)+(Delay 100ms)+C+O+R+T+A+N+A+(Enter)

   ...literally spelled it in the search bar. Works like a charm. Cortana does not open in speech mode, so I added the voice to text keyboard shortcut (Windows)+H to another button. With my particular mouse this is actually quite effective. Your mileage may vary :)